# Moodle Show on Login page not showing? Is it an error?

Tags: authentication, settings, moodle, issue-tracking

Hello I got the following version of moode: 4.2.1 and I run into the following issue:
[image]

While in the Documentation above the Require email verification there is one more option that says: `Show on Login page`   .As u can see here it doesnt showing. As I show u need to enable the Oath 2 from the plugins authentication which I already did but nothing happened . Anyone got any idea why it is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

The image in the documentation is out of date. The checkbox has been replaced by the form field "The service will be used", which you can see near the top of your included screenshot.

Once you save your service configuration, you will also see a tick in the 'Login' column of the "OAuth 2 services" table, indicating that the service will be available on the login page. Of course you also need the auth_oauth2 plugin enabled for this to work.